# Make users with a lot of closed questions reread the "asking in private beta" agreement

Tags: feature-request, users, closed-questions, how-to-ask-private-beta

Some users ([avoiding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lashon_hara) the "naming and shaming," but I think we all know a couple of users for whom this is the case) here don't seem to understand that the serially low-quality questions they ask need improvement, even though they've been strongly DVed and closed en masse.

I think that it might be helpful to show them the "how to ask in private beta" page another few times.

Additionally, I don't think that there is currently a time limit for how long that agreement is shown for before a user can click through. (I think I clicked through it as soon as it was shown on this site's Meta, because I had read it previously on Main) ....perhaps these users should be shown this page for a minimum of 60 seconds before they are allowed to click through.

> Specifically, the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) is to show users who've had *X* number of questions closed (five sounds like a good number to start with, though I'm open to change), be shown the "how to ask" page/agreement again, for *every question they ask*, until they ask five questions in a row that weren't closed.
>   Also, the page should be shown for a minimum amount of time before clicking through, perhaps 60 seconds.

I'm open to changing *X* from five to three, as per comments. I had that in mind originally, but changed it to five because it sounded too harsh. However, it should be noted that (in the words of Tim): "....these people did commit and agree to this earlier. If 3 of your qs are closed, you're doing *something* wrong."

I don't have much experience with sites in private beta, so I don't know if this is necessary by *all* private betas, or just this one, whose precise scope is still under discussion.

Comment: How do you propose we implement this?

Comment: @J.Musser I dunno. I don't know much about programming, to be honest. Hopefully SE staff does ;-)

Comment: @J.Musser [feature-requests] are on-topic on child Metas. I think it's fine here.

Comment: Other than http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th?

Comment: I think 3 may be better. We want the new sites to be high quality, so nipping it in the bud asap is important.

Comment: @Tim I was thinking about 3, but I think that might be a little harsh.

Comment: @J.Musser We could do that too, but I want something extra for private beta, *especially* while we're still under definition, and really trying to raise the quality of questions and answers.

Comment: Possibly, but these people did commit and agree to this earlier. If 3 of your qs are closed, you're doing *something* wrong. Maybe a %? So if 40% of your qs are closed?

Comment: Similarly to how we don't *force* but *encourage* users to take the tour, comment when downvoting, etc, I think it's better to have a popup warning for these users, rather than forcing them on a page for a certain amount of time. I think that will cause more harm than good.

Comment: @J.Musser They don't know what's normal and what isn't in PB; for all they know, this is regular site behavior

Comment: who?‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍

Comment: @J.Musser The users who asked 5 (or 3) questions that were closed.

Comment: Kevin Johnsrude? Matt S.? Both have other SE accounts. Very different users tho. :P

Comment: @J.Musser Matt is a fine user, IMO. I thought we agreed to avoid "naming and shaming," though...... ( *also, other accounts =/= other accounts in private beta; I also have other accounts, but this is my only private beta one* )

Comment: I think if a certain user (not Matt S.) is causing trouble, they need to know about it. Hints aren't helpful.

Comment: @J.Musser Okay. I'll leave him a comment sometime later; I have to run now! ( *btw, you're totally welcome to leave your own comments, if you feel it necessary* )

Comment: Regardless, I think it's not a bad idea to have it pop-up every once and a while. At least until you reach a certain reputation maybe. Kind of like the reminder to leave comments when downvoting.

Comment: Just went to post my first question through the website and finally saw this. I was using the mobile app before and the "how to ask in private beta" never popped up.